# Cost associated with Single sign on

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

Are there any costs associated with using SAML single-sign on with Salesforce? 
Are there any limits with number of calls on a daily basis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no costs associated with SSO from Salesforce. Any licenses that have unlimited logins have unlimited SSO logins as well. Licenses with limited logins share those limits with normal logins.

SAML does impose some additional limitations, so there might be some out of pocket costs. For example, during our implementation, we found we needed a public SSL certificate to support SAML, so we had to pay our CA for a signed certificate for a DNS entry that's not even accessible outside our internal network.

Assuming you have the appropriate hardware and software already in place, the implementation might be completely free or could cost thousands of dollars if you need to build an entire new infrastructure to support SSO.

Comment: thanks for the precise answer you provided, I really appreciate that :)  Can you please also clear - are SAML calls considered against our API limit? Also, we plan to use this with our partner community licenses...for each time a user logs in using that license and then integrates with an outside service via SAML is that considered 2 logins or just 1?

Are there any other considerations to keep in mind when using this with our partner licenses?

Comment: SSO logins are UI logins ("Application" is "Browser"), and while it's difficult to tell if there are API calls used in our organization, as we have a lot of stuff running all the time, the documentation does not state that API calls are used, so it's probably safe to assume that it doesn't. Logins only count against logging into a salesforce.com account, not logging into external services from salesforce, so I'd assume only one login is used. I can't think of any other major hurdles, other than actually configuring SSO correctly (took us a while to figure it out).